# ssrs password accessing report builder

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-administration

After successfully installing SQL Server Express 2012. I am trying to get set up my Report Builder. Unfortunately  I am asked for a password when clicking on the Report manager URL or the Web Services URL. It says something like this (connecting to "my_Pc").

As far as I am aware I do not have any password on my PC nor set up one when configuring my SQL Server. Please note that I have not configure SSRS yet and my Service account is still ReportServer$SQLExpress. How do I sort this out please
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One  easy solution  for  this is to check the browser you are using . |I was using internet  explorer edge and realise that explorer edge  was simply not trusting that site. So if you are  on explorer just go on setting and trust the site.
However I was on IE edge which does not trust any site. I changed it for google chrome. Everything  is running perfectly fine. just change the browser (Internet Explorer best as Google could pose problem to visualize data when creating reports) and refresh everything should be running just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Issue is with how you have created data source for Report.

Data source is created with option "Prompted Credentials" .

It should be created with "Stored Credentials" or "Windows Integrated Security"

Read [more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/store-credentials-in-a-reporting-services-data-source)

Comment: OK. How do I  go sort that that out? do I need to de-install and re-install?

Comment: go throw steps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-data/specify-credential-and-connection-information-for-report-data-sources

Comment: no need to re-install it just redeploy your report in report sever.

Answer (score 0):

At one point you might have configured the user "sa", have you tried using sa login to access the report page? If you are using machine id to authenticate with sql server, to configure a new user,  after you connect to your database, browse down to security > logins > right-click and choose "new login".

Comment: what do you mean by 'sa' and I do not have any form of authentication in my machine; None on the SQL server none on my computer.

Comment: "sa" is the administrator use of MSSQL. You need some kind of authentication to login into a database, either by username or by windows authentication.

You can read more about the differences here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/choose-an-authentication-mode